# RocksDB Crashing with Assertion failed: (i == 0 || start_level_score_ <= vstorage_->CompactionScore(i - 1))

Tags: c++, ios, c, rocksdb

I am using the rocksdb version 6.22.1 on iOS and have encountered the error below. I have compiled the library using the flags TARGET_IOS="IOS", ROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX, ROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX, PORTABLE, -DNPERF_CONTEXT, -DNIOSTATS_CONTEXT, IOS_CROSS_COMPILE=1

I have tried running it on both the iOS simulator and an actual device, and encountered the same error.

```
Assertion failed: (i == 0 || start_level_score_ <= vstorage_->CompactionScore(i - 1)), function SetupInitialFiles, file compaction_picker_level.cc, line 171.
dyld4 config: ...
Assertion failed: (i == 0 || start_level_score_ <= vstorage_->CompactionScore(i - 1)), function SetupInitialFiles, file compaction_picker_level.cc, line 171.
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPad mini (6th generation) (0371B73D-7572-42AE-A485-202AC4371D1E) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) - DeviceType: iPad mini (6th generation)
```

I am using the RocksDB Wrapper (https://github.com/koraykoska/rocksdb.swift) and updated the version to v6.22.1 with the flags and files changed appropriately.
To test the library, I am running a loop where upto 20000 entries are put in a db with the following line

```
db = try! RocksDB(path: FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString), prefix: "")
for i in 1...20000 
{
    try! db.put(key: "\(i)", value: "\(i): Lorem Ipsum") 
}
```

The code crashes with the above error and at index i=10745.
I am looking for help in resolving this issue.

TIA

Comment: *The code crashes* -- Some terminology corrections -- the code *asserts*, meaning it detects that you did something wrong and reported it by comparing values to see if they are equal to the expected values.  An assert is *not* a crash.   A crash would be something like a seg fault, access violation, etc.

Comment: I do agree. In my case, the assertion happens, and fails, and causes the app to crash. This seems to be while the rocksdb platform is doing background compactions.